# Write to []string from multiple json files using iotil.ReadAll()

Tags: json, go

I have a problem with getting information from json files during reading it from directory. I don't understand, why when i wrote code it's not working at all.

```
func FilePathWalkDir(root string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    return files, err
}

var s []string

func main() {

var (
        files []string
        err   error
    )

files, err = FilePathWalkDir("D:/Go/Go_project/Go_pro/files")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for _, file := range files {
    //fmt.Println("Index for json:", index)
    jsonFile, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error:", err)
    }

    defer jsonFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &s)
    log.Printf("Unmarshaled: %v", s)

}
```

}

After this, i got:

```
2020/06/21 13:10:03 Unmarshaled: []
2020/06/21 13:10:03 Unmarshaled: []
2020/06/21 13:10:03 Unmarshaled: []
```

Json files:
First:

```
{
    "name":"Kate",
    "date":"2013-04-23T19:24:59.511Z",
    "data":"is nice"
}
```

Second:

```
{
    "name":"Gleison",
    "date":"2012-04-23T19:25:00.511Z",
    "data":"is a good person"
}
```

Third:

```
{
    "name":"Rodrigo",
    "date":"2013-04-23T20:24:59.511Z",
    "data":"is kind"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to unmarshal in slice type []string, while data inside file is map type map[string]string.

Slice type is: **["1", "2", "3"]**, and Map type is: **{"name": "Andrew", "age": 33"}**.

Please, read about [slices](https://gobyexample.com/slices) and [maps](https://gobyexample.com/maps).

```
func FilePathWalkDir(root string) ([]string, error) {
    var files []string
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    return files, err
}

// var s []string !
var s map[string]string

func main() {
    files, err := FilePathWalkDir("D:/Go/Go_project/Go_pro/files")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        jsonFile, err := os.Open(file)
        if err != nil {
            // ???
            log.Println("Error:", err)
        }

        defer jsonFile.Close()

        byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &s); err != nil {
            // always check errors
            panic(err)
        }
        
        log.Printf("Unmarshaled: %v", s)

    }
}
```

Comment: how can i convert map[string]string to []string? is it possible?

Comment: because i really need type []string

Comment: _"because i really need type []string"_ ok, then please show us what you would like your `[]string` to contain, _exactly_: I rather doubt that's actually what you want. If you don't need the map's key, you should state this clearly in the question. Dan has addressed the types very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the map[string] string to the [] string, you can use the following method

```golang
var strs []string
strs = append(s[key],strs)
...
```

But this method will make you lose the map's key.
Why do you use []string instead of map.